# Can I install linux on my full disk (Complete Erasing) and then factory reset to get back windows 8.1 ? or do i have to resort using recovery disk?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

I have Windows 10 now .I want to use full ubuntu by completely erasing disk and if i want to use windows again will factory reset work or do i have to create a system repair windows disk and use it to restore

Comment: Do you have only one hard drive? And you want to completely erase it & install Linux?

Comment: yes.Iam using a laptop btw

Comment: i just want to know if i completely format my hard disk and install linux will factory reset work and can i restore windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have only one hard drive, if you completely erase it (and then install Linux, but that part's irrelevant once the drive's been erased) then there will be no Windows left on your drive to restore from.

You'll need at least a recovery disk or USB to restore Windows, it can't "resurrect" itself after being completely erased.

Comment: can u pls tell me how a u tube link .thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. At any rate, if I were you I would back up all my important data to somewhere safe, and create a Windows recovery disk/USB before attempting to erase the drive or install Linux. [Googling windows recovery disk](https://www.google.ca/search?q=windows+recovery+disk) shows lots of helpful looking links, apparently just going to Windows's own search (or Control Panel) and searching for "recovery drive" should work.

Comment: Thank You..Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Will the windows after restoring be valid i.e)Will it be activated ? because i have a legit one right now

Comment: Welcome :) Kind of strangely, saying only "thanks" isn't recommended on StackExchange sites (there would end up a flood of "thanks" posts everywhere), so upvoting or selecting as correct (clicking the green check-mark) is a preferred way of saying thanks.

Comment: Will the windows after restoring be valid i.e)Will it be activated ? because i have a legit one right now

Comment: If you use your just-made windows recovery drive, then I think it should be. It might check with Windows's servers again though, I'm not positive, so a "not really yours, but activated somehow anyway" might run into trouble...?

Comment: So its better to keep a small part of windows always..and if i want to use windows again shrinking linux and extending windows partition...right ?

Comment: It depends, if you want to run Windows again easily & quickly, then keeping Windows and dual-booting Linux would be a good idea. I'd still make a recovery drive & backup of important data before installing to dual-boot, sometimes installing gets confusing or buggy and overwrites everything by mistake.

Comment: I have done a lot.. of dual booting but i am new to completely erasing disk and restore point and recovery so i just wanted to know more.I try new linux operating systems by dual booting instead of virtualization..  :) and also i have a disk partition that says HP Recovery from the time i bought my laptop so if I install without disturbing that D:Recovery partition can i resintall windows..?